# Skype API SendMessage sends pending message (C#)

Tags: c#, api, skype

I've used the skype api before and I recently started using it again, except this time, when I call the method, the message stays pending forever
(http://prntscr.com/e79zlb)

Any work around for this?

Btw i'm using Skype4COM 1.0 Library

EDIT: apparently the skype api is no longer supported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skype API Message output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924460/skype-api-message-output)

Comment: The skype api is no longer supported. @geminiousgoel