# Skype Api Wont Send Messages c#

Tags: c#, skype4com

When I try to send a message with the Skype API it will just stay pending. Please help. Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skype API Message output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924460/skype-api-message-output)

Answer (score 0):

There is no work around right now to my knowledge as they disabled it in an old update skype4com library is quite old now